# Conditional Check

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a conditional code dependent on if the user has the left or right bar disabled. I have the following

```
<?php

$left_sidebar = 'off';
$right_sidebar = 'on';


if ($left_sidebar == 'on' || $right_sidebar == 'on') {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $center_width = 'eight_columns';

} else if ($left_sidebar == 'on' || $right_sidebar == 'off') {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $center_width = 'twelve_columns';

} else if ($left_sidebar == 'off' || $right_sidebar == 'on') {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $center_width = 'twelve_columns';

} else {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $center_width = 'sixteen_columns';
}

echo $left_sidebar_width;
echo '<br />';
echo $right_sidebar_width;
echo '<br />';
echo $center_width;
echo '<br />';

?>
```

The problem I have is no matter what I change $left_sidebar or $right_sidebar to it always says

```
four_columns
four_columns
eight_columns
```

What am I doing wrong that makes it not change when I turn one of the sidebars to off?

Comment: I think you want `&&` operator not `||` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have:

```
$left_sidebar = 'off';
$right_sidebar = 'on';
```

and that you are using "OR" logical operator, it will always match the first `if` statement because `$right_sidebar` is `on`. Change the "OR" `||` operator to "AND" `&&` and you should get expected results.

```
if ($left_sidebar == 'on' && $right_sidebar == 'on') {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $center_width = 'eight_columns';

} else if ($left_sidebar == 'on' && $right_sidebar == 'off') {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $center_width = 'twelve_columns';

} else if ($left_sidebar == 'off' && $right_sidebar == 'on') {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'four_columns';
   $center_width = 'twelve_columns';

} else {

   $left_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $right_sidebar_width = 'disabled';
   $center_width = 'sixteen_columns';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement currently evaluates to `TRUE` if **either one** of the conditions are true. What you need to do is check if **both** the conditions are true. So, you need an `&&` instead of `||`.

**Explanation:**

You can check the result of the conditional statements with `var_dump()`:

```
var_dump(($left_sidebar == 'on' || $right_sidebar == 'on'));
var_dump(($left_sidebar == 'on' || $right_sidebar == 'off'));
var_dump(($left_sidebar == 'on' || $right_sidebar == 'on'));
```

The above code outputs:

```
bool(true) 
bool(false) 
bool(true)
```

Changing it to:

```
var_dump(($left_sidebar == 'on' && $right_sidebar == 'on'));
var_dump(($left_sidebar == 'on' && $right_sidebar == 'off'));
var_dump(($left_sidebar == 'on' && $right_sidebar == 'on'));
```

produces the output:

```
bool(false) 
bool(false) 
bool(false)
```

Refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) for more information.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic operator it's wrong, for example over here:

```
else if ($left_sidebar == 'on' || $right_sidebar == 'off') {
```

you are saying if left it's on or right its off do something, but you want if left it's on AND (&&) right it's off do something. Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) it might be useful